# 0xFF0000FF An integer literal does not conform to the expected type kotlin.Int

Tags: kotlin

Why doesn't this work:

```
var color: Int = 0xFF0000FF
```

and why do I have to call `toInt()`

```
var color: Int = 0xFF0000FF.toInt()
```

Comment: because `0xFF0000FF` is not an integer already, so you have to convert it to an integer if you want your `color` variable to be that type.

Comment: @dubstylee What if I have the same, but for "long" type? converting to long won't help, no? 0xFF0000FFFF0000FF , for example...

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This is a bug in the compiler, feel free to vote / watch it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-2780

Comment: Partially under KT-2780, but now the rest of it and the part affecting this is under [KT-4749](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-4749)

Comment: As of today it's still a bug in Android/Kotlin ver 1.2.41

Comment: Still a bug in Kotlin 1.3.10 :(

Comment: This S.O. question has thousands of views but these kotlin bugs only have dozens of votes. Please take a minute to vote on these issues, if they impacted you.

Comment: The related issue now is https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-4749

Answer (score 1):

I am using boolean an in my case I was using this way with same error

```
var shouldShowOnBoarding by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
```

Previous import was

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
```

Then I changed it to

```
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
```