# Property setter with different type

Tags: properties, kotlin

Considering the following example, is it possible to have a setter for `x` that accepts an `Int` and another one that accepts a `Double`?

```
class Test(x: Float) {

    var x: Float = x
        get() {
            return field
        }
        set(value) { // 'value' is of type 'Float'
            field = value
        }

}
```

Reason: If I want to assign a new value to `x` I always have to append the `f` postfix to every assignment, i.e.

```
var v = Test(12f)
v.x = 11   // error: 'The integer literal does not conform to the expected type Float'
v.x = 11.0 // error: 'The floating-point literal does not conform to the expected type Float'
v.x = 11f  // ok
```

Comment: That's a good thing, that prevents bugs to happen, by the caller not realizing that the property must be a float. You shouldn't change anything to the code, except using a double instead of a float.

Comment: Fixed this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/69901984/8663316

Answer (score 1):

Although you cannot overload the setter you can take advantage of the [`Number`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-number/) interface and simply accept all numbers and convert them to floats:

```
class Test(x: Float) {
    var x: Number = x
        get() {
            return field
        }
        set(value) { // 'value' is of type 'Number'
            field = value.toFloat()
        }
}
```

This means that not only `Float`, `Int`, and `Double` are accepted but also `Byte`, `Short`, `BigInteger`, `BigDecimal`, `AtomicInteger`, `AtomicLong`, `AtomicDouble`, and any other class that implements `Number`.

Answer (score -1):

What about:

```
class Test(x: Float) {
    var x: Float = x
        get() {
            return field
        }
        set(value) { // 'value' is of type 'Float'
            field = value
        }

    fun setX(value: Int) {
        x = value.toFloat()
    }
}
```