# Declaring Byte in Kotlin does compile-time error 'The integer literal does not conform to the expected type Byte'

Tags: kotlin

As seen another question in [0xFF0000FF An integer literal does not conform to the expected type kotlin.Int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33023949/0xff0000ff-an-integer-literal-does-not-conform-to-the-expected-type-kotlin-int)

I declaring value 0xFF as Byte

```
val b: Byte = 0xFF
```

receiving

> The integer literal does not conform to the expected type Byte

compile error. Since I have clue about `kotlin.Byte` **is signed byte**

How to declaring Byte in Kotlin with `0x00` - `0xFF` unsigned byte just like [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) `Byte b = 0xFF` ?

If you want instant compiler for testing and answer:
[rextester](http://rextester.com/l/kotlin_online_compiler) , [try.kotlinlang.org](https://try.kotlinlang.org/)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Kotlin doesn't automatically convert between number types.

If you do `val b:Byte = 0xFF.toByte()` then it compiles and results in a byte with value `-1`.

If you want to hold the unsigned byte value then you need to store it as a `Char`, but you will need to convert it to another type to print it as a number:

```
val b = 0xFF.toChar()
println(b.toInt())
```

Comment: Yes, but the question mentions declaring it with an unsigned byte I added the part about using `Char`. `-1` would be the correct answer with signed bytes.

Comment: `0xFF.toByte()` did the thing. appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin now supports [unsigned integer types](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/unsigned-integer-types.html):

```kotlin
val b: UByte = 255u

val c: UByte = 0xFFu
```